# Boost timer: how to get time when I need?

Tags: c++, boost, timer

So I read this [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/timer/timer.htm) but I still do not see how to do such simple thing

```
int main() {
    //stuff
    startTimer();
    // do stuff
    int i =getTimerValue();
    //stuff
}
```

so to get execution time of stuff that I've done. How to do such thing?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want to retrieve the time elapsed since the last restart of the timer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `boost::timer`

```
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
int main() {   
  boost::timer t; // start timing
  ...
  double elapsed_time = t.elapsed();
  ...
}
```

Note that the destuctor of a `boost::progress_timer` will display the time. So use scope if your aim is just to display time elapsed in the middle of a function.

```
int main() {  
  {
    boost::progress_timer t; // start timing
    ...
  } // elapsed time displayed here when t is destructed
  ...
}
```

Comment: Although your first snippet of code answers the question the `boost::timer` does not display the time elapsed on destruction so the second half of your answer is incorrect. For this you need `boost::progress_timer` as described by Steve below. See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/timer/timer.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Replace this with

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
void function()
{
   progress_timer t;  // start timing
   // do stuff
   return 0;
}
```

and you will get what you want, not using `printf` though.

Timer starts on construction and displays on destruction (ie. at fn exit.).  This is a typically [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) way of doing scoped tasks (timing, locking etc.) in C++.

Comment: thats my point - to return time value not when function ended, not showing time value until part of function stopped working.

Comment: @Kabumbus: In that case, use `<boost/timer.hpp>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the following idea based on the mentioned feature that the elapsed time is showed by destructor.

```
#include "boost/timer/timer.hpp"
int main()
{
  // ...
  boost::timer:auto_cpu_timer *boost_timer = new boost::timer:auto_cpu_timer();
  // we want to measure the time of execution of this part of code
  // ...
  delete boost_timer; // show the elapsed time
  // then we can repeat
  boost_timer = new boost::timer:auto_cpu_timer();
  // ...
  delete boost_timer;
  // ...
}
```